# How to find a list of open source / free pdf editors?

Tags: pdf

```
 brew search --casks pdf
```

returns

```
abbyy-finereader-pdf        pd                          pdf-toolbox                 pdfpenpro
cisdem-pdf-converter-ocr    pdf-converter-master        pdfelement                  pdfsam-basic
combine-pdfs                pdf-expert                  pdfelement-express          pdfshaver
epub-to-pdf                 pdf-images                  pdfextractor                rwts-pdfwriter
foxit-pdf-editor            pdf-over                    pdfify                      sejda-pdf
master-pdf-editor           pdf-reader-pro              pdfkey-pro                  wkhtmltopdf
nitro-pdf-pro               pdf-squeezer                pdfpen
```

The goal is to identify as many pdf editors as possible (maybe there is another good search term besides pdf?), and reduce the list to those that are free and preferably open source.   Any suggestions regarding process are appreciated.  Thank you

To be clear: I am asking a question regarding the process of identification and elimination, not a suggestion for software application.  That being said, all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: To identify a PDF editor, you’d ideally have to look at the formulae/cask description. You can try `brew info —all | grep -i “PDF Editor”` to get any thing with this term. Disclaimer:  I use MacPorts, so I cannot test this.

Comment: Does it have to be Homebrew?  A [search on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22pdf+editor%22+stars%3A%3E4&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) for “PDF Editor” with 5 or more stars yields 37 results

Comment: Define "Editor". Something that alters PDF documents? I've written loads of python scripts that do that.  Also: As far as I know, Nitro-PDF-Pro is paid-for GUI app. It's certainly not open source.

Comment: 1) Homebrew is not a good way to find exhaustive lists. It is just those that have a Homebrew formula. 2) AFAIK there are no free and good PDF editors - that might simplify your search :)

Comment: @Allan there is no `brew info -all`

Comment: Foxit isn't open source, either, and the free product is limited in its editing capabilities. If you're looking for an automatic method of collating a list of software types, then I don't think there is one. (Also, GhostScript is notably absent here.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a starting point.

A list of PDF related applications running on Macs: [MacUpdater PDF search](https://macupdater.net/app_updates/search.html?q=pdf).

The MacUpdater list is based on apps installed on Macs using the MacUpdater product. The search includes apps with PDF in the tile, in the short description or in the more detailed product description.

This is probably as exhaustive a list as you are likely to get. Certainly way larger (is that better?) than Homebrew.

But, this is only a starting point. You might want to add "edit" as an additional search term as an attempt to only show those that have some editing capability.

The MacUpdater product pages (follow link on each title) include an indication of cost (free, low, medium, etc.). That will help to eliminate those that are not free.

The product pages do not include any details of license, but do have links to the vendor's home page. You will need to go to these to determine license and cost.

To be honest, I have doubts that any free product is what I would call a good PDF editor.